# What is redshell sushi or rødskjell sushi?

Tags: fish, sushi, shellfish

[image]

This is a rødskjell sushi in Norwegian (where I point with the sticks) and translated as redshell sushi in English. I am trying to find what it is. They have used some green to roll it around, it is probably some sea thing. Is it a fish or is it something else?

Comment: Three "green thing" is almost certainly nori, a dried sea weed product.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to a few sushi websites, red shell sushi is known as arc shell, akaki or akagai sushi. It is a type of clam that gets its red color from lots of hemoglobin in its flesh.

[One source](http://www.aboutsushi.net/index.php?page=cookbook)
[Another source](http://www.sushiencyclopedia.com/sushi_menu/arc_shell_sushi.html)

And the green stuff is definitely nori.

Comment: It's also often just called "clam" or "red clam", I think - you'll find a lot more pictures with that particular red+white look if you search for red clam sushi instead.

Answer (score 4):

It's a type of [clam (shellfish)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantic_surf_clam) the red bit is the "foot". The strip will be nori as @SAJ14SAJ pointed out.